# Datatables, exceed, join

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have Datatable called `sourceTable` with columns `source_Id`, `title` and `programme_Id`. Second Datatable is `credits` with columns `credit_Id`, `programme_Id`. All columns are type of Int instead of column title.

Column `programme_Id` in datatable `credits` is a foreign key FROM datatable `sourceTable`

What I want to achieve is to Exceed table `sourceTable` with Column `credit_Id` from datatable `credits`.

I wrote a code that works, BUT VERY Slow, is there a better way !, FirstOrDefault will put 0 if there is no item that I'm looking for, maybe would be better return null value instead 0 for that case

```
sourceTable.columns.Add("credits_Id");
var rowColl = credits.AsEnumerable();
foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
{
    var credits_Id =
        (from r in rowColl
         where r.Field<int>("programme_Id") == Convert.ToInt32(row["programme_Id"].ToString())
         select r.Field<int>("credits_Id")).FirstOrDefault<int>();

    row["credits_Id"] = credits_Id;
}
```

Comment: both datatables have some content filled from xml document

Comment: I think you don't need to convert to ToString in Convert.ToInt32(row["programme_Id"].ToString()

Comment: it helps a little bit (for a one minute :), I'm in kind of trouble couse there is a LOT of rows

Answer (score 0):

It works slow because you iterate though all rows in credits table for each row in source table. You may use the following linq query to join both tables.

```
(from sourceRow in sourceTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
join creditRow in credits.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
   on sourceRow.Field<int>("programme_Id") equals creditRow.Field<int>("programme_Id")
select new {sourceRow, creditRow})
   .ForEach(o => o.sourceRow["credits_id"] = o.creditRow["sourceRow"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that google brought someone here: this is solution to my question that I reached for now :)

```
var q = from c in sourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                    join o in credits.AsEnumerable() on c.Field<int>("programme_Id") equals o.Field<int>("programme_Id") into outer
                    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {

                        title=c.Field<string>("title"),

                        credits_Id = (o==null)?-1:o.Field<int>("credits_Id")
                    };
            var qToList = q.ToList();
```

now we Can convert this list to Datatable:

```
public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        DataTable dtToConvert = new DataTable();
        try
        {

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            dtToConvert.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
        }
        foreach (T t in list)
        {
            DataRow row = dtToConvert.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                row[info.Name] = info.GetValue(t, null);
            }
            dtToConvert.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        } catch(Exception ex)
            {


            }
        return dtToConvert;
    }
```

Cheers !